# Manually change color of framebuffer

Tags: opengl, glsl, framebuffer

I am having a scene containing of thousands of little planes. The setup is that the plane can occlude each other in the depth.

The planes are red and green. Now I want to do the following in a shader:
Render all the planes. As soon as a plane is red, substract 0.5 from the currently bound framebuffer and if the texture is green, add 0.5 to the framebuffer. 
Therefore I should be able to see for each pixel in the texture of the framebuffer: < 0 => more red planes at this pixel, = 0 => Same amount of red and green and for the last case >0 => more green planes, as well as I can tell the difference.

This is just a very rough simplification of what I need to do, but the core is to write change a pixel of a texture/framebuffer depending on the given values of planes in the scene influencing the current fragment. This should happen in the fragment shader.

So how do I change the values of the framebuffer using GLSL? using gl_FragColor just sets a new color, but does not manipulate the color set before.

PS I also gonna deactivate depth testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fragment shader cannot read the (old) value from the framebuffer; it just generates a new value to put into the framebuffer.  When multiple fragments output to the same pixel (overlapping planes in your example), how those value combine is controlled by the BLEND function of the pipeline.

What you appear to want can be done by setting a custom blending function.  The `GL_FUNC_ADD` blending function allows adding the old value and new value (with weights); what you want is probably something like:

```
glBlendEquationSeparate(GL_FUNC_ADD, GL_FUNC_ADD);
glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_ONE, GL_ONE, GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
```

this will simply add each output pixel to the old pixel in the framebuffer (in all four channels; its not clear from your question whether you're using a 1-channel, 3-channel, or 4-channel frame buffer).  Then, you just have your fragment shader output 0.5 or -0.5 depending.  In order for this to make sense, you need a framebuffer format that supports values outside the normal [0..1] range, such as `GL_RGBA32F` or `GL_R32F`

Comment: Thank you. That was what I was looking for. This is a very elegant way to solve my problem.